# Unable to call correct .NET overload when passing string[]

Tags: powershell, tfs-sdk, azure-pipelines

I have a method I'm trying to call from powershell, it's

```
 Workspace.GetPendingChanges(string[] items)
```

Of this method there are multiple overloads, but the ones making my life hard are:

```
 Workspace.GetPendingChanges(string items)
 Workspace.GetPendingChanges(string[] items)
 Workspace.GetPendingChanges(ItemSpec[] itemspecs)
```

I'm grabbing a list of files using the `Find-Files` cmdlet from TFS 2015's new build tasks:

```
if ($ItemSpec.Contains("*") -Or $ItemSpec.Contains("?"))
{
    Write-Verbose "Pattern found in solution parameter. Calling Find-Files."
    Write-Verbose "Calling Find-Files with pattern: $ItemSpec"    
    [string[]] $FilesToCheckin = @(Find-Files -SearchPattern $ItemSpec -RootFolder $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)
    Write-Verbose "Found files: $FilesToCheckin"
}
else
{
    Write-Verbose "No Pattern found in solution parameter."
    [string[]] $FilesToCheckin = @($ItemSpec)
}
```

And then I call:

```
$pendingChanges = $provider.Workspace.GetPendingChanges( @($FilesToCheckin))
```

I've tried about any version of casts `[string[]]` forced array notation `@()` I know, but the result from find-files is always converted to a single long string, before being passed into the correct overload:

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetPendingChanges" with "1" argument(s): "TF400889: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters:
```

**This is the "long string" that's generated**

```
C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\UpgradeTemplate.xaml C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\checkin-changes.ps1 C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\update.txt C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\updatefile.ps1.
```

```
Specify a shorter path." ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.InvalidPathException: TF400889: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters: C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml ...
    at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()
    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.GetFullPathWrapper(String path)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.GetFullPathWrapper(String path)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.GetFullPath(String path, Boolean checkForIllegalDollar)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionControlUtil.GetFullPath(String item, PathLength maxServerPathLength)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ItemSpec..ctor(String item, RecursionType recursionType, Int32 deletionId)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ItemSpec.FromStrings(String[] paths, RecursionType recursion)
    at
```

**This indicates it's calling the correct overload**

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.GetPendingChanges(String[] items, RecursionType recursion, Boolean includeDownloadInfo)
```

The cmdlet returns a `List<string>` following:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    base.ProcessRecord();
    if (!this.IncludeFiles && !this.IncludeFolders)
    {
        this.IncludeFiles = true;
    }
    List<string> sendToPipeline = FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles(this.RootFolder, this.SearchPattern, this.IncludeFiles, this.IncludeFolders);
    base.WriteObject(sendToPipeline, true);
}
```

To ensure I got a list from the call to `Find-Files` I added:

```
Write-Verbose "Found files: " -Verbose
Write-Verbose $FilesToCheckin.Count -Verbose
```

Which returns: 7, as expected.

### My Question

How do I prevent Powershell from converting the result from `find-files` into one long string before passing it to `GetPendingChanges`?

Project available at, broken code commented out at the bottom:

- https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-tfvc-tasks/blob/master/vsts-tfvc-checkin/TfvcCheckin.ps1

Comment: How about `$provider.Workspace.GetPendingChanges($FilesToCheckin)`?

Comment: is converted into a single long string.

Comment: Which PowerShell version do you use?

Comment: Version 5.0.10586.12, the one that ships with Windows 10

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior on v2 but not on v5. Are you sure that `$FilesToCheckin` is array of multiple strings but not array of single string?

Comment: It returns 7 items, as I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this works, but after adding `@()` and casts to `[string[]]` everywhere and removing the `Write-Verbose $FilesToCheckin` it works:

```
if ($ItemSpec.Contains("*") -Or $ItemSpec.Contains("?"))
{
    Write-Verbose "Pattern found in solution parameter. Calling Find-Files."
    Write-Verbose "Calling Find-Files with pattern: $ItemSpec"    
    [string[]] $FilesToCheckin = @(Find-Files -SearchPattern $ItemSpec -RootFolder $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)
}
else
{
    Write-Verbose "No Pattern found in solution parameter."
    [string[]] $FilesToCheckin = @($ItemSpec)
}

$pendingChanges = $provider.Workspace.GetPendingChanges( [string[]] @($FilesToCheckin) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried invoking the method via reflection to force the right overload? Something like:

```
[Object[]] $parameters = @($stringArray)
$methods = $provider.Workspace.GetType().GetMethods() | where {$_.Name -eq "GetPendingChanges" -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.ToString() -eq "System.String[]" } | Select-Object $_
$methods[0].Invoke($provider.Workspace, $parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I seem to worked around it with arcane syntax variations.